# Select2 - Textfield instead of dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, select2-rails

I'm using Select2 with dynamic ajax loading/filtering.

What i want is a textfield like the one you can see under "Multi-Value Select Boxes" here:
http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

But all i get is a dropdown. This is part of my code:

```
= f.input_field :community, :class => :communities

$(".communities").select2({
  allowClear:true,
  ajax: {
      ...
  },
  formatResult: formatResult,
  formatSelection: formatResult
});
```

What do i have to do to get a textfield instead of a dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

I think `createSearchChoice` is the function you need.

read more at [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) search for createSearchChoice

```
$(".communities").select2({
 createSearchChoice(term)

});
```

Comment: This creates a dropdown as well. Besides i don't want to allow multiple values.

Comment: but i don't want the user to enter free text, only the supposed results

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$('.communities').select2({
   width: '100%',
   allowClear: true,
   multiple: true, 
   ajax: {
     ...
   },   
});
```